# «Мильтон в юбке» — что это значит?

Tags: значение-слов

Из книги Булата Окуджавы «Упразднённый театр» (в Интернете текст есть [здесь](https://profilib.site/chtenie/69427/bulat-okudzhava-uprazdnennyy-teatr-19.php)):

> *Но он не знал, как сказать всё это, да с Сильвией и не поспоришь: она как **мильтон в юбке.***

Можно предположить, что это женщина, обладающая качествами английского поэта Джона Мильтона, но чем в таком случае последний выделялся?

Comment: Речь о солдафонке. Ударение на ***о***: мильтОн. **МИЛЬТОН**. *Милиционер. От уг. «мильтон» в том же зн.* https://russian_argo.academic.ru/6576/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> обладающая качествами английского поэта Джона Мильтона,

У Окуджавы "мильтон" со строчной. Так что — вряд ли.

Хотя...

> но чем в таком случае последний выделялся?

Тут действительно может быть аллюзия (вероятно невольная) на поэта...

Мильтон, Джон - английский поэт, философ, мыслитель.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD,_%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BD
Считался непревзойденным мастером политического памфлета и непревзойденным спорщиком. 
Помните у Ильфа и Петрова: "Еще один великий слепой выискался — Паниковский! Гомер, Мильтон и Паниковский!"? Это про него.

Но должен признать, что на фоне бытоописания обитателей московских домов поминание того Мильтона действительно выглядит чем-то совершенно инородным. Шут знает, может и правда имелся в виду обычный участковый милиционер.

Comment: Я тоже склоняюсь к тому, что имелся в виду мент, милиционер. Просто не знал и не попалось такое значение сначала. А про аллюзию интересно, вдруг, правда, и она имела место. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Мильтон** - устаревшее и именно *детское*, "тинейджерское" наименование **милиционера** в 60-е годы прошлого века. Не совсем верно определять его как "*то же, что и мент*", как это делают в некоторых словарях: дело в том, что эти слова прочно расходятся во *времени употребления*. Параллельно с "**мильтоном**" в те времена широко использовалось менее дипломатичное "**легавый**". Можно вспомнить реплику персонажа Ланового из фильма "Петровка, 38": "Теперь понимаете, за что нас *легавыми* называют?" Слово же "мент" сначала использовалось в более старые времена (употребляется в фильме о милиции времён Гражданской "Трактир на Пятницкой" - в момент выхода фильма оно не употреблялось и казалось диковинкой; в фильме его употребляли только преступники), а начиная примерно с 80-х и вероятно, не без скрытых пропагандистских усилий, при помощи "старого нового" слова "мент" слово "легавый" было полностью вытеснено из обихода.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Интересно) "Легавый" слышал, а "мильтон" до того нет (а если и слышал, то пропускал, не задумываясь, кто это).

Comment: *в 60-е годы прошлого века.* - вот тут-то и нестыковка. Повесть о событиях послереволюционных-довоенных, а написана она в конце 80-х... 60-е там рядом не лежали...

Comment: Это уже о языке самого автора (насколько он уместно применяет его к прошедшим временам). Мне попадались тексты о второй мировой с "фотками" в письмах  с фронта и о первой мировой с "откатами". А чего стоит выражение "завалить Берию"!

Comment: Кстати, здесь интересен и "грузинский след": не могло ли на языке автора (в аспекте устойчивости всеми забытых слов) подсознательно сказаться его происхождение (есть похожее грузинское имя Мелитон)?

Comment: Позволю себе не согласиться с Вами. Вы не обратили внимания на дату, указанную мной в комментарии, — Бритый человек, 1930 год (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Мариенгоф,_Анатолий_Борисович) По другим сведениям — 1926 год. В двадцатые годы слово уже было.

Comment: Это значит лишь одно: как и слово "мент", это слово тоже имело периоды хождения и полного забвения. В 60-е его употребляли именно подростки. Возможно, взрослые, памятуя предшествующую мрачную эпоху, поначалу опасались применять к представителям власти неформальные слова.

Comment: Саша, когда на вечере Окуджавы ему передали записку на грузинском, он сказал: не понимаю, не знаю языка. Ну провел он пару студенческих лет в Грузии, однако остаётся русским поэтом. Какой "Мелитон"!

Comment: Грузинский язык отличается от мегрельского. Мелитон Кантария был мегрел, как и тифлисский папа Окуджавы.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, здесь слово "мильтОн" - детское сокращение от слова "милиционер". Хотя слово детское, но в каких-то ситуациях его мог бы и взрослый употребить. Во всяком случае, по смыслу оно здесь подходит, в отличие от Джона Мильтона.

Answer (score 1):

В словаре Ефремовой:
[мильтон](https://xn--b1algemdcsb.xn--p1ai/wd/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD)
м. разг.-сниж.  То же, что мент.

*Я спросил **милиционерскую** спину:

— Товарищ, как пройти в Спасско-Голенищевский?

Спина, сверкнув медными зрачками, важно повернулась.

Будь в эту минуту на моем месте моя жена, она бы непременно занозисто воскликнула: «Жак! Голубчик! Неужели, роковулечка, это вы? Поручик? Гусар смерти? С черепом? С косточками? Ой, дорогушечка, как к вам катастрофически не идет **мильтонский колпак**!»*
[А. Мариенгоф. Бритый человек](https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/37335/76/Mariengof_-_Brityii_chelovek.html)

Время, описываемое в произведениях, приблизительно одно и то же (двадцатые‒тридцатые годы прошлого века).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма! Странно, что *как **к** вам... не идёт.*

Comment: Да, я тоже обратила на это внимание. Думаю, что ТАК было возможно писать в ТО время (1930). "Щас" порыскаю немного — для полной уверенности.

Comment: Вот, нашла. _Нет, Мари, решительно это **не идет к вам**. Я вас лучше люблю в вашем сереньком ежедневном платьице: пожалуйста, сделайте это для меня_ (Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир). http://croquis.ru/49.html

Comment: Спасибо, интересно! И *лучше люблю* тоже забавляет.))

Comment: И Вам **спасибо c плюсом** за вопрос — нечасто, конечно, но это слово в нашей семье используется.

Comment: Какое именно? Мильтон? Что-то мне подсказывало, что ударение надо ставить на последний слог, а не как в фамилии поэта. Когда читал, "ударил" именно на О.

Comment: "Быстро-последний" комментарий. Конечно, мильто́н.